# SMTP server to server communication without authentication?

Tags: c++, networking, smtp

I'm trying to integrate SMTP with one of my applications written in C++.  My goal is to be able to send emails directly to the SMTP server associated with the email address without authentication. In other words, I want my application to act as an SMTP server and communicate with other SMTP servers.  For example, email being sent from yahoo.com to gmail.com.

Comment: That's how most server to server communications works. Your question seems to be missing a question though.

Comment: I hope this can be an useful example of smtp relay/proxy http://emailrelay.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about is setting up an open mail relay smtp server .  While these used to be the norm on the internet, due to the hordes of spammers abusing them, they are generally frowned upon.

If you are setting up the open relay inside of your private subnet, and only people inside your subnet can send email through it, then it is still an acceptable practice.  However, if you let access in from the outside, it is a good way to end up on internet email blacklists.

For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you need to perform a DNS lookup of the domain portion of a recipient's email address (ie "gmail.com" for "user@gmail.com") asking for its MX records.  That will give you a list of that domain's SMTP hosts.  You can then loop through that list, in priority order,  attempting to connect to each host until one succeeds, then you can carry on a normal [SMTP conversation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and send it commands like `HELO`/`EHLO`, `MAIL FROM`, `RCPT TO`, and `DATA` to deliver the email.